# Do not allow INSERT in table during execution of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

During the execution of a particular stored procedure (i.e, while it is running), I do not want to allow any `INSERT` into a given table in the database, queue it, and then insert it after the procedure execution is complete. How can I do this in SQL Server?

**Edit**: the procedure does not insert anything, it calculates some metrics, whose size changes if new data is inserted during the execution. Hence, I want to prevent insertion during the execution of the stored procedure.

Comment: If you use RCSI you don't have to worry about changing data...

Comment: Can I set it on one particular table?

Comment: No, RCSI is a database level option. Another option is SNAPSHOT isolation, where it would be isolated to the proc. This does require the `ALLOW SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` db option turned on.

Comment: Any guide on how to do it? @DanGuzman

Comment: @DanGuzman can I set snapshot isolation on a particular table ? and not the entire database? does this reduce the speed/performance in any way?

Comment: @heisenbug29 i reccomend creating #temp table of the table inside your procedure and use this #temp for your calculations.  if its not the solution ,  just use tables like this : SELECT * from table with (HOLDLOCK) inside your proc

Comment: It's a database option. When you turn set `ALLOW SNAPSHOT ISOLATION`, there is additional 14-byte overhead per row and increased tempdb usage for the version store.

Comment: you can run a transaction and just select nothing from the table with tablockx so it gets locked, and then do your thing in the procedure. Like: begin tran

select *
from yourtable with (tablockx)
where 1 = 0